# Webpack config error: An appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to set up webpack with Babel to compile React files. The webpack config is autogenerated in VSCode with the Webpack extension. I tried adding the "@babel/preset-react" in the presets section, however, it does not work and this error appears:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:16)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

It appears thar webpack is ignoring the "@babel/preset-react"? The config is as follows.

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'index.js'),
  watch: true,
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: "bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
      ],
      exclude: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
      ],
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: [
          ["@babel/env", {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": "last 2 chrome versions"
            }
          }],
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ]
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join('/dist/'),
    inline: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080,
  }
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loader options are given in the `options` property in the latest version of Webpack, not `query`.

You also don't need both the `include` and `exclude` properties. The `exclude` will be enough.

```
{
  test: /.jsx?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: "babel-loader",
  options: {
    presets: [
      [
        "@babel/env",
        {
          targets: {
            browsers: "last 2 chrome versions"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
}
```